# What happen when we assign a reference to a variable?

Tags: c++

```
void func(){
    int a = 1;
    int b = a; // copy assignemnt
    int &c = a; // nothing?
    int d = c; // nothing?
}
```

For example, when we assign reference `c` to `d`, is there anything triggered (move, copy, etc.)?

What if `d` is an instance member? Is it safe to store a local variable reference into it?

Comment: "c" is just a different name for "a"; `int d = c;` means exactly the same as `int d = a;`. (But none of those are assignments, they are initializations.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> when we assign reference c to d, is there anything triggered (move, copy, etc.)?

Your terminology's getting me confused!  If you're talking about `d` and `c`, I assume you're referring to `int d = c;`  I'd describe that as "assigning whatever `c` refers to to `d`".  "Assign reference c to d" sounds too much like `int& c = d;`.

Your code has:

```
int &c = a; // nothing?
int d = c; // nothing?
```

In the first line, nothing happens that you need to care about... `c` can be thought of as a nickname or alias for `a`.  (At a hidden implementation level, it may or may not help to image `c` being an automatically-dereferenced pointer variable, and your `int &c = a;` being similar to `int* p_c = &a;` - it doesn't copy or move any `int` values around, nor change `a` in any way.)

In the second line, the variable `d` is assigned a copy of the value from `a`.

> What if d is an instance member? Is it safe to store a local variable reference into it?

You're thinking of this the wrong way.  When you assign to a member reference, you're assigning to the referenced object, and not the reference itself.  The referenced object will be another `int` somewhere, and assignment from one `int` to another works as usual.

Answer (score 1):

```
int &c = a;
```

`c` now refers to the same memory as the variable `a`.  It doesn't matter where `a` is instantiated.  When followed by

```
int d = c;
```

`d` gets the value in the memory referred to by `c`, that is, the same memory as `a`, Which contains a `1`.   So now `d==1`.

Since `d` is not a reference, it has its own memory (regardless of where that is) and its own value.

Of course, if you were instead to say

```
c = 2;
```

then the memory referenced by `c` (that is, the same memory as `a`) is assigned the value `2`.   So now `a==2`.  It also doesn't matter where `a` is declared; it's still assigned to `2`.

Answer (score 0):

A reference creates an alias to another variable.

`int &c= a;` makes `c` an alias of `a` and `int d= c;` has the same effect as `d= a;`

A reference is safe, as its lifetime is shorter than that of the variable it points to.